# In Flutter, I am making a bible app using a json file of the format shown bellow... I want you to help me with the Drop Down selection

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-dropdownbutton

I want a dependent dropdown selection for

1. The Book Name (Independent)
2. The Chapter (Dependent)
3. The Verse (Dependent)
   I Want the Dropdown to be in this format

**First, Independent Dropdown**

*Select using the name*

**Second, Dependent Dropdown**

*indexes of the chapters' children*

**Third, Dependent Dropdown**

*select using the index of verse texts*

This is how the json format looks

```
[![\[
  {
    "name": "Genesis",
    "chapters": \[
      \[
        "Verse 1 texts",
        "Verse 2 txts",
        "Verse 3 txts",
        "Verse 4 txts",
        "Verse 5 txts"
      \],
      \[
        "Verse 1 texts",
        "Verse 2 txts",
        "Verse 3 txts",
        "Verse 4 txts",
        "Verse 5 txts"
      \]
    \]
  },
  {
    "name": "Exodus",
    "chapters": \[
      \[
        "Verse 1 texts",
        "Verse 2 txts",
        "Verse 3 txts",
        "Verse 4 txts",
        "Verse 5 txts"
      \],
      \[
        "Verse 1 texts",
        "Verse 2 txts",
        "Verse 3 txts",
        "Verse 4 txts",
        "Verse 5 txts"
      \]
    \]
  }
\]][1]][1]
```

Comment: https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ use this web to covert your json code into dart and then use it

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do,
make a list of chapters as a seperate json file and connect the first dropdown to that list
then for the second list should show the number of chapters of the first book

```
json[selectedBook].length
```

then for the third dropdown

```
json[selectedBook][selectedChapter].length
```

then the selected verse can be retrived by

```
json[selectedBook][selectedChapter][selectedVerse]
```